# Waiting for Async value in firebaseRef.on listener

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I'm looking how wait for the value passed from an async function before calling the .set() method of firebase ! Eg. there the code that doesn't works !

```
// main.js 
firebaseRef.on('value', snap => {
   if(snap.val()) {
     otherFirebaseRef.set({
       // here i want set the a field with result returned from async function 
       a: (await??) asyncFunction()
     })
   }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the [callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#callback:-function) function `async` and do as follows:

```
firebaseRef.on('value', async snap => {
   if(snap.val()) {
     const theValue = await asyncFunction();
     otherFirebaseRef.set({
       a: theValue 
     })
   } 
})
```

Comment: @cicciosgamino Hello, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?